# What is the dual function of this non-overlapping Group Lasso's penalty?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, lasso, duality

I'm trying to find the dual function of this function (non-overlapping Group Lasso's penalty function):
$$ \mathfrak{h}: \mathbb{R}^p \to [0,\infty], \ a \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^{k} \left\| a_{\mathscr{A}_j} \right\|_{2}$$
where $\mathscr{A_1},\dots, \mathscr{A_k}$ are disjoint partitions of $\left\{ 1,\dots,p \right\}$, that is $\bigcup_{j=1}^{k} \mathscr{A}_j=\left\{ 1,\dots,p \right\},\ \mathscr{A}_j \not=\emptyset \ \forall j, \text{and} \ \mathscr{A}_i \cap \mathscr{A}_j \not= 0, \ \forall i\not= j.
$. The (Hölder) dual function definition is (according to https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-73792-4):

Given a function $\mathfrak{h}: \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}$, we define $\bar{\mathfrak{h}}:\mathbb{R}^p \to [-\infty,\infty]$ through $$\bar{\mathfrak{h}}: a \mapsto \sup \left\{ \langle a,c \rangle: c \in \mathbb{R}^p, \mathfrak{h}(c) \le 1 \right\}, $$
where $\langle a,c \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^{p} a_{j}c_{j}$ is the standard inner product. We call $\bar{\mathfrak{h}}$ the dual function of $\mathfrak{h}$.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you try calculating it using identities for convex conjugates?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate
Plus, shouldn't it be $\mathscr{A}_i \cap \mathscr{A}_j \ne \emptyset$?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. I've edited the post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dual norm is $$a\mapsto \max_{1\leq j\leq k}\|a_{\mathcal{A}_j}\|_2.$$

By Cauchy-Schwartz for every $c$ with $h(c)\leq 1$, we have
$$\langle a,c\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^k\langle a_{\mathcal{A}_j},c_{\mathcal{A}_j}\rangle \leq \max_{1\leq j\leq k}\|a_{\mathcal{A}_j}\|_2.$$

Then it is enough to find a single $c$ with $h(c)\leq 1$ for which the equality holds. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265721/proving-that-the-dual-of-the-mathcall-p-norm-is-the-mathcall-q-norm

Comment: Thanks, I have found a $c$ such that $c_{\mathscr{A}_j} = \frac{a_{\mathscr{A}_j}}{\left\| a_{\mathscr{A}_j} \right\|_{2}}, \ \text{and}\ c_i=0, \ \forall i \notin \mathscr{A}_j. $, the bound is attained.